# Submit button stops to work after adding ajax call in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've a contact form. If I define route in action, it redirects user to a proper route. But I want to handle this form with Ajax not with simple loading of page.

After writing jQuery code for ajax call, my submit button has stopped to work. Onclick, it does nothing.

I need to know what I' m doing wrong and how would I treat it with ajax call?

Blade

```
<form method="post "action="javascript:void(0)" id="updateprofile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
@csrf
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
   <input type="hidden" id="zoom" value="$user->zoom">
   <input type="hidden" id="is_submitted_firsttime" value="$user->is_submitted_firsttime">

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
   <button type="button" id="myaccount_edit" class="btn">Edit</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
$("#updateprofile").validate({
    rules: {
        name:"required",
        email:"required",
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
      $("#location").keyup(function(event){

          if(event.keyCode == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
              $('#submitbtn').addClass('testing')
          }
          else{
              $('#submitbtn').removeClass('testing')
          }
       });
       if (!$('#submitbtn').hasClass("testing")) {
          var serializeData = $('#updateprofile').serialize();
              $.ajax({
                  url: "{{ route('myaccount.ajax_store') }}",
                  data: serializeData,
                  dataType: 'json',
                  contentType: false,
                  cache: false,
                  processData:false,

                  success: function(response){
                      if(response==true){
                        $('#company-logo').attr('disabled','disabled');

                      }
                      else{
                        setTimeout(function() {
                              toastr.options = {
                              closeButton: true,
                              progressBar: true,
                              showMethod: 'slideDown',
                              timeOut: 4000
                              };
                              toastr.error('Something went wrong!');
                          }, 1300);
                      }
                  }
              });
        }

    }

});
```

Controller

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
     function ajax_store(Request $request)
    {

                 dd(1);
     }
}
```

Comment: name and email input are required, but they are not seen in the html.

Comment: @Ale
They are in the form. I myself showing very limited fields just to elaborate problem